# can I attach electric cable to underside of rafters

Tags: electrical

I am rewiring several fixtures in the basement.
Can I attach electrical cables to the underside of the rafters in the basement?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/39783/33) provides the appropriate code section.

Answer (score 1):

Joists actually, but I get you. Otherwise, only if you want to nick them & have to re-wire after every electrocution. To do wire on the joist bottoms you have to use Armored Cable or some kind of approved conduit. Really just not a good idea, much easier yes but definitely not better. Plus, drilling through the center of the joists isn't that bad & the basement could be finished in the future with less corrections to make.